# Rikulo security client side login

Tags: dart, rikulo

I've been trying to create a Dart SPA using Rikulo security to log in. I have been unable to do so successfully. I found the following in the docs:

```
//If you'd like to login in an Ajax request, SOAP or others,             
//you can invoke this method directly by providing the username, password
//and, optional, rememberMe:                                             

    //prepare username, password, rememberMe from, say, Ajax           
    security.login(connect, username: username, password: password,    
      rememberMe: rememberMe, redirect: false);
```

My question is how do I return a success/fail login value from Rikulo security for use on the client side.
An example would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you'd like to log in over Ajax (and JSON). Basically, it is no different from handling Ajax -- you can refer to the Handle Post requests section [here](http://docs.rikulo.org/stream/latest/Request_and_Response/Form_Handling.html).

```
import "dart:convert";
import "package:rikulo_commons/convert.dart";

Future login(HttpConnect connect) {
  return readAsJson(connect.request).then((Map<String, String> data) {
     return security.login(connect, redirect: false, 
        username: data["username"],
        password: data["password"]);
 })
 .then((_) {
    //login successfully
    response
      ..headers.contentType = contentTypes["json"]
      ..write(JSON.encode({"result": "success"}));
  })
  .catchError((ex) {
    if (ex is AuthenticationException) {
      // login fail
      response
        ..headers.contentType = contentTypes["json"]
        ..write(JSON.encode({'result': 'fail'}));
    } else {
      throw new Http404.fromConnect(connect);
    }
  });
}
```